# Process ethereum transactions in an offchain worker

Tags: evm, offchain-worker, ethereum

I need to process Ethereum transactions in a substrate offchain worker. I already include EVM and Ethereum pallets, but I also need to do some communications with runtime code running as solidity smart contracts from the off-chain worker.

Are there any libraries to parse / generate ethereum transactions, or data that I can use? Or should I build everything from scratch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use some of the tools from: https://github.com/rust-ethereum/.

Namely, if you're looking to create Ethereum transactions in an offchain worker then this should work:

- https://github.com/rust-blockchain/ethereum
- https://github.com/rust-blockchain/ethereum/blob/master/src/transaction.rs