# How to Sign an Ethereum transaction from substrate?

Tags: ethereum, signing, subkey

Consider we have a ETH keypair in the keystore inserted using this command

`curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"method":"author_insertKey","params": ["eths","0x606640b4efd5a1a0bc9839dfce7a7bb5a0c1402d8d02cbee9dabe5d88f977640","0x0209bb17d85c86ad4812103248b6b73e67f96ea66829c3b18f4d1b5df2c72cab63"]}' http://127.0.0.1:9936`

How we can access this keystore in a substrate pallet to sign an Ethereum transaction?

Answer (score 3):

You can not sign from your on chain code. Your on chain code needs to be deterministic. If you don't provide your private key to every node in the network, they could not import the block and while doing this, running the signing code again.

Comment: from OCW context can we do this?

Comment: See: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/254/process-ethereum-transactions-in-an-offchain-worker

Comment: Yes from the OCW context you can sign transaction. This is fine.